# Can pickle dumps be scrambled?

Tags: python, pickle

For an automation project, I have to persist user id/password to allow my scripts to connect to a remote service.

My idea is to use the [keyring](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyring) module to achieve some better level of security; but as not all platforms support keyring; I am looking into storing credentials into a flat file, too. I created a "Credentials" class; and figured that using `pickle` I could just dump/load objects of that class, like:

```
def _store_to_file(credentials):
    from pickle import dump
    pkl = open('whatever.dat', 'wb')
    dump(credentials, pkl)
    pkl.close()
```

Unfortunately, this file gives away the password in plain text:

```
S'_password'
p6
S'bla'
```

I understand that file, stored by a local script isn't offering real security. But I was hoping to at least get to a point where one would need more than a simple "less whatever.dat" to acquire that password text.

I had hoped that pickle has some kind of "scramble" mode; but couldn't find anything. Am I overlooking something?

Alternatively: is there another way to persist my objects that easily, but not that "easy human readable"?

Comment: To be honest I'd create an encrypt and decrypt function using `bcrypt` which would then store a base64 encoded, encrypted password into your pickle file.

Comment: So scramble the data before pickling it

Comment: Maybe https://pypi.python.org/pypi/EncryptedPickle/0.1.4

Comment: @KeefBaker Unless I am mistaken: bcrypt will only allow me to **hash** a password. But I need the password in **plain text** later on. In other words: I need something that gives me encrypt() and decrypt() functions; like codecs with rot13. But maybe 10 percent harder than rot13 ;-)

Comment: My bad, I thought I was using bcrypt in my project. I was actually using `from Crypto.Cipher import AES`

Comment: Any comments by the anonymous downvoter - is there something I could improve about this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution; based on the comment by Keef Baker --- using AES encryption to scramble on password/username; like this:

```
class Credentials(object):

  def __init__(self, user, password):
      self._user = aes.encrypt(user)
      self._password = aes.encrypt(password)

  @property
  def user(self):
      return aes.decrypt(self._user)

  @property
  def password(self):
      return aes.decrypt(self._password)

  from Crypto.Cipher import AES
  aes = AES.new('This is a key123', AES.MODE_CBC, 'This is an IV456')
```

Comment: Upvoted, with the caveat that obviously in real code you wouldn't use rot13, but e.g. [`hashlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html) or, better, [`cryptography`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/), with a key stored in a separate `secrets.py` module (which can be kept out of version control if necessary).

Comment: I don't see that hashlib gives me decrypt/encrypt; but cryptography does ;-)

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus But Keef gave me another good hint; so I reworked to use AES encryption at least.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus As I liked your feedback; feel free to look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43274703/trouble-with-encode-encrypt-pad-using-same-code-for-python2-and-python3 as well ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You should not.

The problem in applications that try to keep a safely encrypted copy of a key is just that they need another key to decrypt it. It could be encrypted too by would need still another key. It could... (sorry joking :-) ). It only makes sense when you have to store multiple secrets, because you unlock the secure vault with one single password - what keyring and password managers do...

For one single password, the correct and portable way is to rely on the OS to provide a secure folder. Both Linux (and Unix-like) and provide either access control rules (only accessible to user), or encrypted folders if you need better security. Just document it and respect the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: I understand all of that. But this is an company internal tool. When some intruder manages to scan the local disk of one of my coworkers; we are already in deep sh... trouble. And just for the record: the same password that we need to talk to that servers I want to talk to ... is also used to talk to our SVN server. And that password sits there in some .svn folder in plain text.